# the least $m$ such that $a^m\equiv 1 \mod n $ for fixed $a,n$.

Tags: number-theory, algorithms, carmichael-function

Is there any known method for calculating $\lambda_a(n)$ which returns the smallest integer $m$ such that $a^m\equiv 1 \pmod n$ where $\gcd(a,n)=1$ ?

I searched but I found nothing, is there at least an algorithm that does not use bruteforce ?

Note : as you may note this is closely related to Carmichael function, the difference is that $a$ is fixed here.

Comment: @MichaelBurr thanks, I fixed it.

Comment: Depends on how large $n$ is. If we can factor $\lambda(n)$, we can start with that, and calculate $a^{\lambda(n)/p}$ modulo $n$ for the various prime factors of $\lambda(n)$.  As long as we get $1$, keep descending.

Comment: This is an instance of the discrete logarithm. Suffice it to say that finding a discrete logarithm is hard, in the sense that there is no classical algorithm that runs in polynomial time. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm#Algorithms

Comment: I'm not looking for a really fast algorithm, just better than trying all $m$ or as I found out trying divisors of $\phi(n)$.

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking for is known as the order of $a$ modulo $n$. The strongest result I know of is that $\text{ord}_n a\mid \phi(n)$.

Comment: Finding $\phi(n)$ is not easy.

Comment: I agree with vudu, take the pseudo prime numbers for example.

Comment: Right, which is why I specified that it was the strongest result I knew of - it's not incredibly helpful, but I don't think there's anything better.